# Problem with GetFileVersionInfo and/or VerQueryValue

Tags: c++, winapi

I am trying to return the CompanyName from an executable that I added a VS_VERSION resource to. I get a zero length string from GetFileVersionInfo (I think this is the problem), resulting in GetLastError returning 1813 from the call to VerQueryValue.

Here is a code snippet of what I am trying to do...

```
TCHAR* pModuleFileName = new TCHAR[MAX_PATH];
BOOL bGetModuleFileName = GetModuleFileName(NULL, pModuleFileName, MAX_PATH);
    
DWORD dwIgnored;
DWORD cbVersionInfo = GetFileVersionInfoSize(pModuleFileName, &dwIgnored);

BYTE* pVersionInfo = new BYTE[cbVersionInfo];
BOOL bGetFileVersion = GetFileVersionInfo(pModuleFileName, 0, cbVersionInfo, pVersionInfo);

TCHAR* pCompanyName = new TCHAR[MAX_PATH];
UINT cbCompanyName;
BOOL bVerQueryValue = VerQueryValue(pVersionInfo, _T("CompanyName"), (LPVOID*)pCompanyName, &cbCompanyName);
```

Any ideas?  Thank you.

Comment: Did you look up error code 1813?

Comment: Hi Alex, welcome to StackOverflow. Type `net helpmsg 1813` on the command line to get a human readable description of that error. +Your code leaks memory. Declare your buffers like this instead `TCHAR pModuleFileName[MAX_PATH];`. Adjust variable names to your taste.

Comment: Hi.  Yes, I did.  It means "The specified resource type cannot be found in the image file. "  That is not the problem.  The problem is that I'm getting the 1813 in the first place.  Thank you.

Comment: And possibly (probably) I'm getting a zero length string from GetFileVersionInfo.

Comment: Also, I know the code as stated leaks memory.  (I only included a simplified snippet.)  Thanks

Comment: Shouldn't that be `_T("\\StringFileInfo\\CompanyName")` in the call to `VerQueryValue`?

Comment: [Maybe this helps?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11237928/how-to-use-verqueryvalue).

Comment: Sorry, that did not work.  I even tried it without the leading \\'s. I still get 1813.  Any other ideas?

Comment: So you didn't try the accepted solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11237928/how-to-use-verqueryvalue)?  You need the language codepage, i.e. `StringFileInfo\\lang-codepage\\string-name`).  I remember doing this a very long time ago, and it was more work than what you are showing just to set up the call to `VerQueryValue`.

Comment: Did you check that the version-info correctly displays in executable properties ? BTW ,You should always check the return values of the Windows API functions.

Comment: If the OS is reporting error 1813, then "The specified resource type cannot be found" probably *is* the problem. Just saying "That's not the problem" doesn't make it so.

Comment: Please standby.  I am integrating your suggested code changes into my program.  I'll get back to this when I have results.  Thanks.

Comment: [Does Windows show these properties for the executable?](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1274449/why-is-only-the-first-translation-in-the-varfilein)

Comment: must be `(void**)&pCompanyName` and not need allocate memory for it.

Comment: Thank you everyone for responding.  I was able to get this working correctly. The problem was that I was not getting the language and code page.  Here is the final code, with all the error checking included.

Comment: Thank you everyone for responding.  I was able to solve the problem with the help I got.  The problem was that I was not getting the language and code page, and that I was forgetting that I was delaing with Unicode - The VersionInfo structure starts with a zero byte and that's why it seemed to be a zero length string. This can be closed, but I don't know how to do that.

Comment: You can answer yourself and mark as completion.